# declare a variable Column based on a cover sheet

Tags: vba, excel

```
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim CopyRange As String

    iRow = (ActiveCell.Row)
    Let CopyRange = "M" & iRow & ":" & "T" & iRow

    Range(CopyRange).ClearContents
```

i have this code and i need to declare the second part of CopyRange ("T" & iRow) as a variable based on my cover sheet.

Columns M to X respresent the 12 months, 
so whenever i change the cover sheet to Septemper for example an Input sheet changes the value to 9, so when i use the choose methods it chooses current month which is column U in this case.

what i need to do is to clear all content but current month when i change the cover, column M (jan) to column T (Aug), in this case.

i've been thinking of something like this:

```
    Sheets("Inputs").Range("H3") = C
    Let CopyRange = "M" & iRow 
    let iCopyRange = C-1 & iRow 

    Cells (CopyRange, iCopyRange).ClearContents
```

its kinda weird !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to access ranges (and columns). For the kind of functionality you are after, it sounds better to not rely on letters. You can do something like:

```
Dim startCol As Long: startCol = 13  'Col M
Dim curMonth As Long: curMonth = 8 'August
Dim endCol As Long: endCol = startCol + curMonth - 1

Range(Columns(startCol), Columns(endCol)).ClearContents
```

This code takes the given month in numeric format and clears the contents of all the previous months including the input one. Note that you don't need to add the `Sheets("Inputs").` bit if you are working all the time with the same worksheet. If you are changing the worksheet, it might be better to add it in order to avoid problems:

```
Sheets("Inputs").Range(Sheets("Inputs").Columns(startCol), Sheets("Inputs").Columns(endCol)).ClearContents
```

UPDATE:

If you are not interested in deleting the whole columns, but just certain rows (for example, just `iRow`); you should rely on `Cells`:

```
Range(Cells(iRow, startCol), Cells(iRow, endCol)).ClearContents
```

Comment: still second part (current month -1) is not variable based on my cover sheet? 
or did you mean, 
Dim curMonth As Integer: curMonth = Sheets("Inputs").Range("H3")

Comment: @FadelNaeem I meant curMonth = the value you want :)

Comment: @FadelNaeem is not my answer what you were looking for? Please, take a look at my update (deleting just one row) and let me know about your concerns.

Comment: Don't use `Integer`, use `Long` instead.

Comment: @brettdj for columns? Why? For rows, I do agree (although, only if required, if you are sure that you will be dealing with small numbers of rows you can safely rely on integer), but what is the need for columns?

Comment: Don't use `Integer` full-stop. `Long` is more efficient as Integers are converted to Long regardless. Google it.

Comment: @brettdj honestly I have always tried to use integers as much as possible, but in this context you are right: the functions (row-/column- related ones) expect long and thus a implicit conversion is performed anyway. Thanks will change it right now.